# An object reference is required to access non-static field in C#

Tags: c#, object, unity-game-engine, reference

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyAttack : MonoBehaviour {
    public float timeBetweenAttacks = 0.5f;
    public int attackDamage = 10;
    Animator anim;
    GameObject Player;
    PlayerHealth playerHealth;

    //EnemyHeath enemyhealth;

    bool playerInRange;
    float timer;
    private Animator animator = null;

    void Awake() {
        Player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Player");
        playerHealth = Player.GetComponent<PlayerHealth> ();

        //enemyHealth = GetComponent<EnemyHealth> ();

        anim = GetComponent <Animator> ();
    }


    void Attack(Collider other) {
        if (other.gameObject == Player) {
            playerInRange = true;
            animator.SetBool ("idle0ToAttack1", true);
        }
    }

    void Attack1(Collider other) {
        if (other.gameObject == Player) {
            playerInRange = false;
        }
    }

    void Update() {
        timer +=Time.deltaTime;

        if (timer >= timeBetweenAttacks /*&& enemyHealth.currentHealth > 0*/) {
            AttackPlayer ();
        }

        if (playerHealth.currentHealth <= 0) {
            Destroy (this.Player);
        }
    }

    void AttackPlayer() {
        timer = 0f;
        if (PlayerHealth.currentHealth > 0) {
            playerHealth.TakeDamage (attackDamage);
        }
    }
}
```

The error is giving on last method `void AttackPlayer()  if(PlayerHealth.currentHealth > 0)`.

I am making a first Person Shooter Game in Unity and if possible please tell give me some more suggestions for player dead animator code that I've written above.

Comment: `PlayerHealth` is a class. You can't call an instance method on a class. You need to call it in an instance of a class (an object). Otherwise, what do you expect `PlayerHealth.currentHealth` to refer to? Which player's health?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void AttackPlayer()
{
    timer = 0f;
    if(playerHealth.currentHealth > 0)
    {
        playerHealth.TakeDamage(attackDamage);
    }
}
```

I've corrected the code. It was a simple mistake of using `PlayerHealth` instead of what you meant which was `playerHealth`. Using the uppercase was referring to the class itself. The lowercase would refer to your current object defined earlier in this class.